# If statement stops fully running

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm writing what should be a simple program but I've run into an error. I'm not sure what's going on but as near as I can tell, the program will run the if statement fully, once, and then never run the entire block of code again. I'm at a total loss to figure out where my mistake is.

```
void Update () { 
checker = Mathf.Abs (wheel.transform.position.y) - prevLocation;


    if (checker > 1.9) {
        Debug.Log (checker + "checker");
        pick = Random.Range (0,5);
        rotation = Random.Range (0,360);
        currentLocation = (int) wheel.transform.position.y;
        switch(pick){
        case 1:
            Instantiate(half, new Vector3(0, count, 0), Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3(-90, rotation, 0)));
            break;
        case 2:
            Instantiate(threequarter, new Vector3(0, count, 0), Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3(-90, rotation, 0)));
            break;
        case 3:
            Instantiate(halfB, new Vector3(0, count, 0), Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3(-90, rotation, 0)));
            break;
        case 4:
            Instantiate(quarter, new Vector3(0, count, 0), Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3(-90, rotation, 0)));
            break;
        }
        prevLocation = currentLocation;
        Debug.Log (prevLocation + "prev");
        checker = 0;
        count = count - 2;
        Debug.Log (count + "count");
    }
}
```

What the code is supposed to do is wait for a trigger, which is an object in the game world moving down by a set amount, then it will spawn one of the four prefabs some distance down, thus creating an infinite game. The only reason this code isn't totally killing my computer every time I run it, is I have a patch script that deletes game objects over a certain distance away from the trigger object.

Comment: What do you mean "never run the **entire** block of code"?

Comment: So the debug output works for a while but then prev stops outputting at all, while count and checker do output and some cycles, count runs while checker doesn't output.

Comment: Do you collapse your logs?

Comment: Ah, so I did. As for the error, I think I've figured it out, I needed to make currentLocation be an absolute value.

Comment: You are checking the difference between the current y location and the previous y location. if the difference is greater than your magic number 1.9 your if block will run. Log the checker value. I have no idea what you are doing, but my guess is that if the wheel moves along the y it will always work, but if it moves along x instead y the checker will be less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prevLocation = currentLocation;

Needed to be

prevLocation = Mathf.Abs(currentLocation);